# Cannot override onSubmit handler of the form inside React component

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

my problem is simple but I cannot seem to figure it out and ashamed to even ask it here. I need to prevent full page refresh by my form. I know that I have to override its onSubmit(e) handler and call e.preventDefault() but this is not working somehow, the method is not being called at all. I cant seem to figure it out even after a lot of tries and would be grateful if you can help me! Thankyou!

The complete code is at https://github.com/rajatpundir/url-shortener/blob/master/imports/ui/LogIn.js

```
export class LogIn extends React.Component {

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefualt();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} noValidate >
          <button >Login</button>
        </form>
        <Link to="/signup">Need an account?</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use `preventDefault`instead of `preventDefualt`

Comment: Hi, thanks its working now. I couldn't see the difference at first even in your comment, such silly mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo 'preventDefault' instead of 'preventDefualt'